# How to encrypt folder in Windows?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, encryption, filesystems

I have a program in C++ that stores certain files such as movies, mp3 & Flash in the AppData folder. The issue is that whilst generally hidden, the user can easily visit this folder and take any of these files.

Is there a way that the program can encrypt this folder so that it's not possible for the user to access the files (except through the software itself)?

Any other solutions (even if not related to the above) are much appreciated.

Comment: There is no way to make it impossible, or even intractable. Whatever mechanism you use to encrypt the content, the user can reverse engineer from your program. It depends on the technical sophistication of your users, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use your own program to encrypt a file or a folder.However you can use open source software like  [truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).The software along with the code is available.Code is written in C,C++ and assembly

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you know of any mainstream software that uses TrueCrypt?

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply encrypt the files and then decrypt them when they are loaded by the app.  That way it does not matter if the user can access the files.

Comment: If the "consumer" of those files is a module which can work only with files on the disk (some external application or third-party library), then such trivial approach is too trivial to work.

Comment: Your answer assumes the opposite "if" - if the consumer is capable of consuming generic streams...

Comment: My answer assumes nothing, it merely suggests a solution based on the information provided.